# Ethereum multi signature address

Tags: solidity, contract-development

How can i make a contract in which i need two address to call a function in a contract instead of just one, the first address is the owner of the contract which is compulsory which is known at the time of deploying the contract but the second address is not stated in the contract  because there are thousands of second address so including all of them in contract will consume alot of gas, so any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include a list of allowed second addresses, I can't think of a way to have a really multi-signature contract. The whole point is that the contract should be able to decide by itself whether it has valid 'votes' or not. If you need external input to help the contract to decide it's no longer independent and you lose benefits of the multi-signature system.